# How to split this datatable?

Tags: c#, algorithm, datatable

Please see the description of the picture：
https://i.stack.imgur.com/65enL.jpg

Data source: one row for each category

Purpose: merge by quantity, and the sum of their respective numbers is equal to the respective quantity of the data source

Note: count with ID 1001 is 1 (only the first row exists);
The count with ID 1002 is 2,1 (the first row) + 1 (the second row);
The count with id 1003 is 5,1 (the first row) + 1 (the second row) + 3 (the third row);

Question: how to code a data source into a destination?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Develop_BBS_DataSplitDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dtSource = new DataTable();
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dtSource.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

        var drNew = dtSource.NewRow();
        drNew["Id"] = 1001;
        drNew["Name"] = "Apple";
        drNew["Count"] = 1;
        dtSource.Rows.Add(drNew);

        drNew = dtSource.NewRow();
        drNew["Id"] = 1002;
        drNew["Name"] = "Banana";
        drNew["Count"] = 2;
        dtSource.Rows.Add(drNew);

        drNew = dtSource.NewRow();
        drNew["Id"] = 1003;
        drNew["Name"] = "Orange";
        drNew["Count"] = 5;
        dtSource.Rows.Add(drNew);
        //...The actual number of dynamic rows

        this.gvSource.DataSource = dtSource;
        this.gvSource.DataBind();

        var dtResult = new DataTable();
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Ids", typeof(string));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

        var drResult = dtResult.NewRow();
        drResult["Ids"] = "1001,1002,1003";
        drResult["Names"] = "Apple,Banana,Orange";
        drResult["Count"] = 1;
        dtResult.Rows.Add(drResult);

        drResult = dtResult.NewRow();
        drResult["Ids"] = "1002,1003";
        drResult["Names"] = "Banana,Orange";
        drResult["Count"] = 1;
        dtResult.Rows.Add(drResult);

        drResult = dtResult.NewRow();
        drResult["Ids"] = "1003";
        drResult["Names"] = "Orange";
        drResult["Count"] = 3;
        dtResult.Rows.Add(drResult);

        this.gvResult.DataSource = dtResult;
        this.gvResult.DataBind();
    }
}
```

```aspx
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DataSplitDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Develop_BBS_DataSplitDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h4>Data source: one row for each category</h4>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvSource"></asp:GridView>

            <h4>Purpose: merge by quantity, and the sum of their respective numbers is equal to the respective quantity of the data source</h4>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvResult"></asp:GridView>
<pre>
Note: count with ID 1001 is 1 (only the first row exists);
The count with ID 1002 is 2,1 (the first row) + 1 (the second row);
The count with id 1003 is 5,1 (the first row) + 1 (the second row) + 3 (the third row);
</pre>
            <h4>Question: how to code a data source into a destination?</h4>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see the description of the picture link

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     
        List<Frult> frults = new List<Frult>
        {
            new Frult{ Id = "1001", Name = "Apple", Count = 1 },
            new Frult{ Id = "1002", Name = "Banana", Count = 2 },
            new Frult{ Id = "1003", Name = "Orange", Count = 5 },
        };

        List<Frult> frultsRs = new List<Frult>();
        while (true)
        {
            frults.RemoveAll(f => f.Count <= 0);
            if (frults.Count == 0) break;

            var doneIds = frults.Select(c => c.Id);
            string id = string.Join(',', doneIds);
            var frultGroup = frultsRs.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
            if (frultGroup == null) frultsRs.Add(new Frult
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = string.Join(',', frults.Select(c => c.Name)),
                Count = 1
            });
            else
            {
                frultGroup.Count += 1;
            }

            frults.ForEach(f => f.Count -= 1);
        }

        foreach (var d in frultsRs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", d.Id, d.Name, d.Count));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Frult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```